Moving average process in continuous-time
In statistics, the moving average is usually defined for discrete time series. Is there a continuous-time model for moving average (MA) processes, as there is for auto-regressive (AR) ones?  E.g. in the form of a differential equation.
This is similar to this question asked 10 years ago.
I'm not certain but it seems the answer is yes, based on this 2002 document I found from Dr. Alet Roux at York University:

Some properties of continuous-time
autoregressive moving average time
series models

This document presents models for autoregressive (AR), moving-average (MA), and autoregressive moving-average (ARMA) models in both continuous and discrete time.
Section 3.3 starting on page 36 is titled 'Continuous-time moving average processes'. Here they present the equation for a discrete time MA process then state that

Continuous-time moving average (CMA) processes are defined similarly, by replacement of the difference equation by a differential equation

Which they define as follows.
CMA(q) process for $\{Y(t)\}_{t \in[0, \infty)}$ is defined to be a solution of the differential equation:
$$
Y^{(q+1)}(t)=\varepsilon(t)+\beta_1 \varepsilon^{\prime}(t)+\beta_2 \varepsilon^{\prime \prime}(t)+\cdots+\beta_q \varepsilon^{(q)}(t) \text { for } t \in(0, \infty)
$$
They reference the following source for the definition of this model

Priestley, M. B. (1981), Spectral analysis and time series, Probability and mathematical statistics, Academic Press, London (p. 176).

However, the they state the following about this model in the paper:

The specific form of A in (3.3.3) allows us to calculate the q +1 eigenvalues of A directly: they are all equal to zero. This is consistent with the fact that, in the case of the CMA(q) process, the autoregressive polynomial $\alpha(z)$ (defined in (3.2.13)) reduces to
$$ \begin{aligned} &\alpha(z)=z^{q+1} \text { for } z \in \mathbb{C} . &(3.3 .14) \end{aligned} $$
Unfortunately, in stark contrast to the discrete-time case, Theorem 2.2.10 asserts that $\{Y(t)\}_{t \in[0, \infty)}$ is not asymptotically weakly stationary. Even without referring to Theorem 2.2.10, this disappointing fact is evident from the second term on the right-hand side of (3.3.13); due to its polynomial nature, a limiting covariance matrix such as $\sum$ in (3.1.16) cannot exist.

(see paper for more details)
Could someone explain the implications of these statements from the perspective of practical use/implementation of this model?  Does it mean the model is not stable and therefore cannot be used in practice?

B.t.w. when I provided the answer below to the earlier question linked above, it was deleted and I was told "If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context." So I assume it was deemed not similar enough.

The problem was that you posted a question in an answer box.  That's an automatic deletion--and therefore shouldn't be taken as any kind of comment on the nature or quality of your question or how you have posed it.

@whuber Thanks, yes I realise that was the reason now and corrected it. I am unsure of my answer in any case and I noticed more qualifying statements about it in the paper which seem to disqualify it.  So I decided to include the answer as part of this question now.

@whuber could you please move the comments you made on the answer I deleted below to here? I think they are quite helpful.

The answer appears to be buried in theorem 3.2.3.  On the face of it, a differential equation doesn't involve any kind of moving averages; but a reformulation in terms of Fourier or Laplace transforms very well might reveal a connection, much as in the discrete theory the MA and autoregressive (AR) formulations are connected through a characteristic polynomial and its reciprocal.

Hi: you should probably get this to see what's up in this field. Peter Phillips and Rex Bergstrom are the big econometrics people who dealt with continuous time processes. I don't know if it's freely available. https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/econometric-theory/article/abs/econometric-analysis-of-continuous-time-models-a-survey-of-peter-phillipss-work-and-some-new-results/88F9E0CFC25BC709ED49A1DE66D77891

Here's another one that looks pretty good atleast as far as readability and references. Bergstrom is mentioned quite a bit which is a good sign since he's one of the masters in this area. https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/122678/1/CMT_Chapter_DP.pdf
